# How to detect multiple soap request validation issues while using cxf?

Tags: web-services, validation, cxf, payload

I have been asked to validate the complete request xml and capture all the soap request xml validation issues at once...like what SOAPUI does when we validate the request.

Currently I have only following configuration for validation:

`<jaxws:properties><entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" /></jaxws:properties>`

with this config when the first validation issue is detected a soap fault is thrown. Is there a way to detect all the issues at once and then give a response like following which soapui gives?

`line 6: Expected element 'xyz' instead of 'xyz1' here in element arg0`
`line 15: Expected element 'abc' instead of 'abc1' here in element arg0`
`line 19: Expected element 'abc' instead of 'acb' here in element arg0`
`line 25: Expected element 'abc' instead of 'xyz' here in element arg0`
`line 42: Expected element 'ahd' instead of 'utd' here in element arg0'

Answer (score 0):

There are bean validation (JSR 303) implementations available which can provide all issues in your request bean in a single go...

Look for - ConstraintViolationException and Interface ConstraintViolation.